# Can I hide password in log when making a remote() query?

Tags: clickhouse

I want to transfer some data from production cluster to test cluster. AFAIK the easiest way is to use query like this

```sql
INSERT INTO company.events (id, value)
SELECT *
FROM remote('clickhouse-srv01.example.com', company.events, 'user', 'password')
WHERE <...>
```

The problem is that this query will be saved in `system.query_log` with provided credentials. Is there a way to avoid it? Like for example in bash you can start a command with space and it won't be saved in `.bash_history`.

I know, I can transfer entire partitions from production cluster without exposing password, but it's too much data that I don't need. That's why I want to use `SELECT ... WHERE ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 1 settings log_queries=0
```

or

```
set log_queries=0;
select 1;
```